# nginx ingress rewrite Request webshell

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm having trouble deploying a webshell on Kubernetes using nginx ingress.
I'm rewriting all request going from /apple to / on my backend. The backend is hosting b374k webshell on /
. I'm able to access the webshell form /apple but when I click on something the request is send to / instead of /apple/... which results in 404.
Is it possbile to solve this without changing the webshell's code?

Kubernetes Manifest:

```
#Definition eines Srvices für ein Deployment
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hip-service
  namespace: hip-test
spec:
  selector:
    app: hip
  ports:
    - port: 80
---
#Definition Reverse-Proxy für einen Service
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hip-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  namespace: hip-test
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple
          backend:
            serviceName: hip-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use rewrite-target annotation, `path` field value is treated as regexp and not as a prefix. This is why `path: /` is matched literally and only with `/`.

Taken from the [nginx ingress docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/):

> **IMPORTANT NOTES**:
>   If the `use-regex` OR `rewrite-target` annotation is used on any Ingress for a given host, then the case insensitive regular expression [location modifier](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) will be enforced on ALL paths for a given host regardless of what Ingress they are defined on.

So if you want to use rewrite-target you should do it as following:

```
Definition Reverse-Proxy für einen Service
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hip-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  namespace: hip-test
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple/(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: hip-service
            servicePort: 80
```